# Meaning of "speaking in these alternative spaces"

Tags: sentence-meaning, indian-english

What is the meaning of "they are speaking in these alternative spaces"

Sentence: well you know the experts as I said there are people who are speaking but they are speaking in these alternative spaces

Source of info: https://youtu.be/JEaX_F6VJLE?t=319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainstream sources of information: official government announcements.  Established media companies.

And then there are alternative spaces in which people can speak their opinion: private blogs, facebook, youtube.  These are an alternative to the mainstream media.

The journalist is saying that the official figures for covid infections are wrong, and the true figures can be found by listening to experts speaking in "alternative spaces" like youtube or private blogs.